# I want create a crystal report in gis with writing code

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, vba

I am working in ArcGIS 9.3.1 and I try to write code for creating a crystal report and work with it in VBA, but I recieved an error when the program arrived at this line of code:

```
Dim pProj As CRAXDDRT.Application
Dim pReport As CRAXDDRT.Report
```

The error is "User defined type not defined". Why does the program give this error?
Please help me with this problem.

Comment: " I am working in ArcGIS 9.3.1 and I try to write code for creating a crystal report and work with it in VBA, but I recieved an error when the program arrived at this line of code: " Please i have a similar problem.
I'm looking for a code that permit to create with vba a report in arcgis and print it.
Help me please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the most common errors in ArcGIS/VBA environment, and is usually due to missing references.
Go to Tools --> references and check for any MISSING ones.  Most likely your missing references to Crystal components.
Tick them on and re-try.

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/29069

Comment: tanks alot for answer.Problem is solvate.Again tank you.

Comment: If my answer was the one that helped you solve it, can you give me the credit.  If it was not, can you let every1 know how you solved it?  :)

Comment: I agree, @Nima please hit the green tick on @Simons answer if it helped you.

Comment: Simon, I click on the green tick.that is rigth? or I should do other work?

Comment: Yes, green tick if your happy your answer is resolved.

Comment: Perhaps someone should close this one off.