# finding nearest point to a point

Tags: arcobjects

I work in GIS with VBA. I have 2 Points layer.One of them is City points and another is hydro station points.I want write code in vba for  selecting one point from station layer and finding closest city to this selected point.On the other hand I should find nearest point to a selected point.
Please help me.

Comment: How are the points stored? If they are simply pairs of (X, Y), just sort using the Pythagorean theorem and take the one with the shortest distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id advise searching the [archvied ESRI forums as this will have been asked before.](http://forums.esri.com/SearchResults.asp?c=93&eSortBy=1&eDateLimit=0&eForums=1741&eForums=993&eForums=1742&eForums=1154&eForums=1170&eForums=992&eForums=1147&eQueryType=0&eQuery=nearest+point&btnSearch=search)

[eg1](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=167502&mc=4#msgid696649)
[eg2](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=191627&mc=4#msgid569232)
= You should be able to pinch some code from the snippets found there to at least get you started.

Comment: Tanks Simon.my problem is solved with using this sample code.

Comment: Cool. Can you mark this as resolved please.
You also failed to mark a previous Question I answered for you
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/i-want-create-a-crystal-report-in-gis-with-writing-code/1344#1344
- Can you mark that one as resolved as well please.

Comment: Sorry,But I click the green button next to your name.Should I do other work?

Comment: this would be a better answer if it included one such example snippet or conversation. We can't rely on links to external sites to remain intact, and if/when it does change this answer will become wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the IProximityOperator or the IIndexQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an ArcInfo license, have you tried calling the [Near tool](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Near_%28Analysis%29) within your script? It sounds a lot like what you're after.